# Distance of $n$th roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers

For a natural number $n>1$, consider $n-1$ points on the unit circle of the form $\exp\left( \frac{2\pi k}{n}\mathrm{i} \right)$ where $k \in \{ 1,2,\ldots,n-1 \}$. Show that the product of distances of these points from one is $n$.

Comment: Where exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374357/product-of-the-difference-of-nth-roots-of-1.

Answer (score 5):

This is $|(1-\zeta)(1-\zeta^2)\cdots(1-\zeta^{n-1})|$ where $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/n)$. Let $f(x)=(x-1)(x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^2)\cdots (x-\zeta^{n-1})$. What is $f(x)$, and what is $f'(1)$?